# Column/Row management in Power Query

Tags: microsoft-excel, power, query

I have a .txt file with loads of data in it.  I have it loaded into Power Query thusly:
[let a letter (A) equal a row of data, one column wide]

A
B
C
D
E
A
B
E
A
E
A
B
C
D
E

and so on...

I would like to organize it into rows and columns such that it would now look like

A A A A
B B E B
C E x C
D x x D
E x x E

using the value "A" as a delimiter to determine separation into a new column.
Also, the last value will always be the same, ("E" above) if that is relevant.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but seems like it would be easier to do this with VBA, or possibly with some of the formulas that are available with Office 365 version of excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conceptually simple but does require using the Advanced Editor for the last step

- Create a column that has the same number for each group starting with "A"

  - Add an Index column
  - Add a custom column (Named `Grouper`) with formula `if [Column1]="A" then [Index] else null`
  - Fill down `Grouper`
- Group on Grouper

  - Aggregate "All Rows"
- Add another custom column which extracts, as a list, the values in each subtable column1
- Use those lists to create a new table using the `Table.FromColumns` function

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table26"]}[Content],

    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", type text}}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Changed Type", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Grouper", each if [Column1]="A" then [Index] else null),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom",{"Index"}),
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Removed Columns",{"Grouper"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filled Down", {"Grouper"}, {{"Count", each _, type table [Column1=nullable text, Grouper=number]}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Grouper"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Columns", each [Count][Column1]),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom1",{"Count"}),

    #"New Table" = Table.FromColumns(#"Removed Columns2"[Columns])

in

    #"New Table"
```

***Source Data***
[image]

***Results***
[image]